# node-express too many redirects

Tags: node.js, express

I've got my routes set up like below

When i navigate to 'http://localhost/' i get an error saying 'localhost redirected you too many times' and the URL of the page (showing in the URL bar of the browser) is http://localhost/!/dashboard - so it does look like it is being redirected, but i cannot see why it's getting stuck in an infinite loop

```
 // Public Routes
 app.use('/', function(req,res){
      res.redirect('/!/dashboard');
 });
 app.use('/login', routes.login);
 app.use('/!/dashboard', isLoggedIn, routes.dashboard);

// Check If Logged In
function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
      return next();
    } else {
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
};
```

Comment: What does your `routes.login` look like? (Specifically any redirects to `/` or dashboard?)

Comment: @DominicTobias - the GET to routes.login doesn't have a redirect it simply renders the page but the POST to routes.login does have a redirect after successful authentication with passportjs it has a `return res.redirect('/!/dashboard')`

Comment: Please include the code for `routes.dashboard`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use `app.use('/', ...)`, because that will match any URL *starting* with a `/`.

Instead, use [`app.all`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.all):

```
app.all('/', function(req,res){
  res.redirect('/!/dashboard');
});
app.use('/login', routes.login);
app.use('/!/dashboard', isLoggedIn, routes.dashboard);
```

Answer (score 1):

Classical error would stand in your configuration of Apache/Nginx. In your code, you seem to be using port 80, which I believe you are not using and therefore you would be proxying your requests through Apache or Nginx.

*(can't comment so even though this is a poor answer, I will update it accordingly on further comments)*

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this type of error occurs,  when a website creates a redirect loop. One redirect leads to another and creates a chain that redirects back to itself in a loop, and directs the user between different addresses infinitely.

For example look at this contoller which handle the url '/users/sign_in' request :

```
          module.exports.sign_in=(req,res)=>{

   if(req.isAuthenticated())
   {
      return res.redirect('/question/all_questions');
   }


   return res.redirect('/users/sign_in');

 
 }
```

So here when user want to sign in then at that time this code handle that request.In this code first we check whether the user is logged in or not.If user is already logged in then we can redirect to the given url as "/question/all_questions".

But what if user is not logged in then we again send the request '/users/sign_in',then again it will check whether the used logged in or not and if not logged in then it again send the request '/users/sign_in'.So you clearly see that that it will actually creating an infinite loop if the user is not already logged in.So when this type of situation occur at that time browser automatically break this infinte loop and give error as "too many redirects".
So to solve this problem instead of writing

```
return res.redirect('/users/sign_in');
```

we have to render the page as

```
 return res.render('sign_in');
```

instead of redirecting the url and created the infinite loop.

So i think you have to look at your code carefully that whether is there any inifinte loop is created of which i am taking about at above.